# How to use zap logger with go-kit?

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

I want to use the [go-kit logger](https://github.com/go-kit/kit/tree/master/log/zap) lib with [zap](https://github.com/uber-go/zap) and I want it in this function to return instance
of zap.logger that I will be able to use it like following: (using zap functionality) like

`logger.Info`

or

`logger.WithOptions`

etc

I try with the following to return zap interface but it doesn't work, the methods are not available, any idea what am I missing here?

```
func NewZapLogger() zap.Logger  {

   cfg := zap.Config{
      Encoding:         "json",
      Level:            zap.NewAtomicLevelAt(zapcore.DebugLevel),
      OutputPaths:      []string{"stderr"},
      ErrorOutputPaths: []string{"stderr"},
      EncoderConfig: zapcore.EncoderConfig{
         MessageKey: "message",

         LevelKey:    "level",
         EncodeLevel: zapcore.CapitalLevelEncoder,

         TimeKey:    "time",
         EncodeTime: zapcore.ISO8601TimeEncoder,

         CallerKey:    "caller",
         EncodeCaller: zapcore.FullCallerEncoder,
      },
   }
   logger, _ := cfg.Build()

   sugarLogger := logz.NewZapSugarLogger(logger, zap.InfoLevel)

   return sugarLogger.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go Kit exports their own logging interface. They only provide the `Log` method. It's named `zapSugarLogger` and it's basically a function type matching one of `zap`'s logging function (`Infow`, `Warnw` etc).

Looks like there is no way to access the underlying zap functionality from the `zapSugarLogger` instance.

You can however, create an instance of `zap` yourself and use it as usual.

```
package main

import (
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
)

func main() {

    cfg := zap.Config{
        Encoding:         "json",
        Level:            zap.NewAtomicLevelAt(zapcore.DebugLevel),
        OutputPaths:      []string{"stderr"},
        ErrorOutputPaths: []string{"stderr"},
        EncoderConfig: zapcore.EncoderConfig{
            MessageKey: "message",

            LevelKey:    "level",
            EncodeLevel: zapcore.CapitalLevelEncoder,

            TimeKey:    "time",
            EncodeTime: zapcore.ISO8601TimeEncoder,

            CallerKey:    "caller",
            EncodeCaller: zapcore.FullCallerEncoder,
        },
    }
    logger, _ := cfg.Build()

    logger.Info("Hello")



}
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this thread but I wasnt able to make it work with zap, example will be very appreciated

Comment: If you post your full source code, I would happily modify it and update my answer with it.

Comment: @JhonD I checked out zap code and how it's used in go-kit. Unfortunately, it's implemented in a different way than logrus. I have updated my answer.